# Ayuda con metodo buscar y pagedList C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, searchview

Que tal amigo recurro nuevamente a ustedes para poder solucionar un problema que creo es simple pero no he podido dar con al solución.

1.- resulta que tengo un actions result de la siguiente manera.

```
 public ActionResult searchRequerimiento(searchRequerimiento model)
    {
        var pageIndex = model.Page ?? 1;
        var itemPorPagina = 40;
        ViewBag.pageno = pageIndex;
        ViewBag.itemperpage = itemPorPagina;

        #region busqueda de requerimientos
        DataTable objDataTable = new DataTable("tblSongs");

        objDataTable.Columns.Add("Ejercicio");
        objDataTable.Columns.Add("NoLicitacion");
        objDataTable.Columns.Add("Descripcion");
        objDataTable.Columns.Add("TipoProcedimiento");
        objDataTable.Columns.Add("ClavesRequeridas");
        objDataTable.Columns.Add("PiezasRequeridas");
        objDataTable.Columns.Add("MontoRequerido");
        objDataTable.Columns.Add("ClavesAsignadas");
        objDataTable.Columns.Add("PiezasAsignadas");
        objDataTable.Columns.Add("MontoAsignado");
        DataRow myDataRow;

        var partidaSelec=0;

        foreach (int item in model.itemPartidas)
        {
            if(item!=0)
            {
                partidaSelec = partidaSelec + item;
            }             
        }

        var _filtrado = from t in db.MtoRequerimientos
                        where (model.MtoProcedimientoId == 0 || t.MtoProcedimientoId == model.MtoProcedimientoId) &&
                        (model.Gpo == null || t.Gpo.Contains(model.Gpo)) &&
                        (model.Gen == null || t.Gen.Contains(model.Gen)) &&
                        (model.Esp == null || t.Esp.Contains(model.Esp)) &&
                        (model.Descripcion == null || t.Descripcion.Contains(model.Descripcion)) &&
                        (partidaSelec == 0 || model.itemPartidas.Contains(t.MtoRequerimientoId))                            
                        select t;


        Session["ResumenProcedimientos"] = objDataTable;

        model.result_MtoRequerimientos = _filtrado.ToPagedList(pageIndex, itemPorPagina));

        return View("_LoadResultSearchRequerimiento", _filtrado.OrderBy(r=>r.MtoProcedimiento.NoLicitacion).ToPagedList(pageIndex,itemPorPagina));

        #endregion
    }
```

bien y un modelview de la siguiente manera.

```
public class searchRequerimiento : MtoRequerimiento
{
    [Display(Name = "Procedimiento")]        
    public string NoLicitacion { get; set; }

    public int? Page { get; set; }

    public IPagedList<MtoProcedimiento> result_MtoRequerimientos { get; set; }


    public IEnumerable<MtoProcedimiento> ListProcedimientos { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MtoRequerimiento> ListPartidas { get; set; }

    public int[] itemLicitaciones { get; set; }      

    public int[] itemPartidas { get; set; }
}
```

en lo que quiero pedirles ayuda es como  puedo pasar la consulta a la variable

```
public IPagedList<MtoProcedimiento> result_MtoRequerimientos { get; set; }
```

de mi model, ya que cuando quiero hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```
model.result_MtoRequerimientos = _filtrado.ToPagedList(pageIndex, itemPorPagina));
```

me muestra el siguiente error.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'PagedList.IPagedList' to 'PagedList.IPagedList'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)    WebDBT  C:\Users\Mirobiano\Source\Repos\WebDBT\WebDBT\Controllers\RequerimientosController.cs   103 Active

Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te hace falta castear `model.result_MtoRequerimientos`.

Intenta:

```
 model.result_MtoRequerimientos = (IPagedList)_filtrado.ToPagedList(pageIndex, itemPorPagina));
```

Otra opción puede ser *(en vez de usar var)*:

```
IPagedList<MtoProcedimiento> filtrado = (*tu consulta LINQ*).ToList();
```

Comment: que tal amigo gracias por responder ya intente asi y me manda el siguiente error Gravedad Código Descripción Proyecto Archivo Línea Estado suprimido
Error CS0266 No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'PagedList.IPagedList' en 'PagedList.IPagedList<WebDBT.Models.MtoProcedimiento>'. Ya existe una conversión explícita (compruebe si le falta una conversión) WebDBT C:\Users\horacio.xochitemol\Source\Repos\WebDBT\WebDBT\Controllers\RequerimientosController.cs 104 Activo

Comment: @HoracioXochitemol, otra opción es "en vez de usar var" use `IPagedList<MtoProcedimiento> filtrado = (tu consulta LINQ).ToList();`.

Comment: amigo Mauricio podrías dar un ejemplo muchas gracias.

Comment: @HoracioXochitemol no creo que te pueda ser mas de ayuda - *(no se me ocurre nada mas)*. ¿Intentaste lo de `IPagedList<MtoProcedimiento> filtrado`?